# I want to get the sum of each subject over dictionaries in python using for loop

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I am a novice in python and have been playing with dictionaries. I want sum of each subject using following data structure.

```py
dist = {
    "john":{"maths": 85, "science": 97, "english": 58, "nepali": 62, "computer": 54},
    "mark":{"maths": 59, "science": 95, "english": 96, "nepali": 88, "computer": 69},
    "ram":{"maths": 60, "science": 99, "english": 83, "nepali": 70, "computer": 69},
    "shyam":{"maths": 82, "science": 71, "english": 75, "nepali": 51, "computer": 65},
    "hanuman":{"maths": 85, "science": 81, "english": 67, "nepali": 73, "computer": 71},
}
``
avgs={}
sum = 0
for key, values in dist.items():
    for key2,values2 in values.items():
        for key3,values3 in avgs.items():
            if key3 == key2:
                sum=values2+values3
            else:
                sum= values2
        avgs[key2]= sum
        sum=0
print(avgs)


Actual Output = {'maths': 85, 'science': 81, 'english': 67, 'nepali': 73, 'computer': 328}

Expected output = {'maths': 371, 'science':443 , 'english': 379, 'nepali': 344, 'computer': 328}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show us the expected output and the code you have tried. SO is not a code writting service.

Comment: Hint [`dict.values()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict%20values#dict.values)

Comment: How on earth can `371` be the average of a subject, as you state to be your desired output?

Comment: i meant sum mistakenly typed it average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are showing just the last item here. No need to go over 3 loops like you did.

First, instead of using items(), you can use values(), as that's the only thing important in the first loop. In the second loop, you are going to create a dictionary to store the sum of values.

```
subjects = dict()
sum = 0
for values in dist.values():
    for k, v in values.items():
        subjects[k] = subjects.get(k, 0) + v

print(subjects)
for k, v in subjects.items():
    avg_grade = float(v)/len(dist)
    print(f'{k}: {avg_grade}')
```

Last 2 is printing of sums, and printing of average.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

```
s = {}

for v in dist.values():
    for k in v:
        s[k] = s.get(k, 0) + v[k]

print(s)
```

Output:

```
{'maths': 371, 'science': 443, 'english': 379, 'nepali': 344, 'computer': 328}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below

```
from collections import defaultdict
dist = {
    "john":{"maths": 85, "science": 97, "english": 58, "nepali": 62, "computer": 54},
    "mark":{"maths": 59, "science": 95, "english": 96, "nepali": 88, "computer": 69},
    "ram":{"maths": 60, "science": 99, "english": 83, "nepali": 70, "computer": 69},
    "shyam":{"maths": 82, "science": 71, "english": 75, "nepali": 51, "computer": 65},
    "hanuman":{"maths": 85, "science": 81, "english": 67, "nepali": 73, "computer": 71},
}

sums = defaultdict(int)
for v in dist.values():
    for k1,v1 in v.items():
        sums[k1] += v1
print(sums)
```

output

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'maths': 371, 'science': 443, 'english': 379, 'nepali': 344, 'computer': 328})
```